# How does the regular expression "(aa)+\1" match "aaaaaa"?

Tags: regex, backtracking

Can anyone explain the process that a regular expression engine matches `(aa)+\1` against `aaaaaa`? I know there is a process called backtracking when you use `+` or `*` but I'm not sure how it works in this example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you put the quantifier outside the capture group, it doesn't capture the entire string matched with that pattern with quantifier. It rather matches just the last repetition that pattern matched.

So, `(aa)+` won't capture `aaaa` in capture group, but just the last pair - `aa`, so that it can satisfy the rest of the regex pattern.

So, with `(aa)+\1`, the pattern matches first - `aaaa`, and then the backreference `\1` matches the captured group - `aa`. Thus is matches the string - `aaaaaa`. Not `(aa)+` won't match all the `a's`, because then there will be nothing left over to be matched by `\1`.

Here's the break up of the regex `(aa)+\1`:

- `(aa)+` matches the first two `aa` in the string. Remaining string - `aaaa`.
- There is more to be matched by `(aa)+`, so it goes on to match next `aa`. Remaining string - `aa`.
- Again `(aa)+` can match the remaining string. So it matches the next `aa`. Remaining string - `""`. Remember, the quantifiers by default act *greedy*. They will match as much as they can.
- Now, `(aa)+` can't match any further.
- Next in the pattern is `\1`. But there is nothing left to match.
- Backtrack the last pattern matched by `(aa)+`. Remaining string - `"aa"`.
- Now `\1` again tries to match, and it successfully matches `aa`, since that is what currently in the 1<sup>st</sup> capture group.

---

**References:**

- [Regular-Expressions.info - Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! Could you also comment on what happens if I did this: `(aa+)\1`, where I put the quantifier inside the capture group?

Comment: Maybe I should ask another question "How is `(aa+)\1` different than `(aa)+\1`?

Comment: @bodacydo: `(aa+)\1` will match your given string, with `aaa` for the capturing group. the + quantifier will take all the `a` of the string, and the regex engine will backtrack character by character until the pattern will match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. OOPs. Missed that quantifier is now on `a`, and not `aa`.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` quantifier means "1 or more". The `\1` refers to the captured group, which is the same thing the quantifier is referring to. So effectively, it's saying "group aa, 1 or more times, and then one more time". Which is the same as "2 or more times".

So the regex might be clearer as this: `/(aa){2,}/`

Since `aaaaaa` is three sets of the `aa` group, the regex matches the string.

Comment: This doesn't explain *how* the matching is performed(i.e. backtracking), which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario:

```
aa           # the group is matched
aaaa         # the group is repeated once, cause the + quantifier
aaaaaa       # the group is repeated once again, always cause 
             # the + quantifier (and because it is greedy and take all it can.)
             # But since all the characters are eaten, and there is \1
             # the pattern will fail.
aaaa         # the regex engine must backtrack to try another way because of \1
aaaaaa       # you are arrived! (the 2 last "a" are for the \1
```

You can verify this behaviour using a possessive quantifier (++) that forbid backtracks:

```
(aa)++\1            # will never match
```